# How to update django model objects if no update has happened over time(say 10 seconds)

Tags: python, django, time

In my use case, I'll keep getting data from different devices for every 10 seconds when they are **Active**  (active=True)

When ever I receive data I'll update particular django object(database). But I'll never come to know if any device is inactive.

It's clear that, if I'm not getting data for every 10 seconds I should mark that object to active = False

In my database, almost 100k records exists and couldn't perform cron or any script for all records to update.

Is there a way to mark active = False automatically if no update happened to any object over time in particular model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually need them *marked* as active?

How about simply recording the time of the latest update and make `active` a computed property?

```
from django.utils import timezone

# in your model, remove the "active" field
# and store the last update's datetime in a "last_update" field
# then...
@property
def active(self):
    delta = timezone.now() - self.last_update
    return delta.total_seconds() < 10
```

That's how it's typically done if you don't need to run some code precisely when the state changes: you simply compute it based on data that does not need to be updated asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply spectras. I can update the field if Im getting the data from device. But the requirement is model should update when I dint receive any data from device.   Say object got updated at 05:30:10 PM today.. if I dint recieve any data @05:30:20 PM that object has to be marked as inactive

Comment: in brief for every 10 seconds objects has to be monitored whether now - updated_time < 10

Comment: Are other programs using the database as well? Because if the database is only accessed from django, you'll see that `device.active` will change from `True` to `False` 10 seconds after the last update. Only difference is it's not backed by an actual database field, it's generated on the fly.